# How to navigate on the another page after google sign in

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

```
  Future<void> signUpWithGoogle() async {
try {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
      await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user =
      (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;

  return user;
} catch (error) {
  print(error);
}
}
```

I have done that above code to sign in with google and called  the function of google sign button  like this

```
    signUpWithGoogle().then((value) => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return HomePage();
        })));
```

But on first time when apk is installed normally the app is asking for choosing the google account 
But after log out when i tap on the google SignIn button it is not asking in pop up menu to select the account.
And one more problem is their on clicking on the google signin button firsts it goes to the HomePage() then signIn is hapenning.

```
  @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
getCurrentUser();
}



  Future<void> getCurrentUser() async {
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
bool result = await facebookSignIn.isLoggedIn;
if (user != null && user.isEmailVerified == true) {
  print("Email");
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
    return HomePage();
  }));
} 
 }
```

Is this is the correct method to navigate to the HomePage() for those users who is signed in when app starts

Answer (score 0):

1. Whenever user logout and sign in again with google account android is smart enough to provide google account directly to the app without giving sign in pop up
2. for your second problem plz ref this answer -:
   [Why might a function not get called in initState(){ super.initState()} in flutter, but work perfectly fine if called later in the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61121266/why-might-a-function-not-get-called-in-initstate-super-initstate-in-flutte/61121682#61121682)

Answer (score 0):

first of all i am also new to flutter so this might not be the best solution however this is what i implement in my app for the authentication part

first i created a User class that contain an ID for the user 
then i created a stream of user to my app so the app will always be provided with this value and what ever change happen to it in my services this is the code

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Stream<FirebaseUser> user; // firebase user


User _userFromFireBaseUser(FirebaseUser user)  {
return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
}

// //auth change user stream
Stream<User> get userStream {
return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFireBaseUser);
// or we can use .map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFireBaseUser(user) );
}
```

in my  main widget

```
StreamProvider<User>.value(
      lazy: false,
      value: AuthService().userStream,
      child: MaterialApp()//your main widget
```

then i created a statless wrapper class that read the stream value and according move to a page, in my app i used the wrapper to go to the sign in if the user is null else go to the profile page, in your application i guess it will go to the homepage

```
class ProfileWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
//print(user.uid);
if (user == null) {
  print('no user');
  return SignUpPage();
} else if (user != null) {
  print('there is user');
  print(user.uid);
  return ProfilePage();

  // print('there is user' + user.displayname);
  // print('there is user' + user.photourl);
 }
 }
 }
```

also you need to add the provider package in your pubspec.yaml file

```
provider: ^4.1.1
```

by doing this you don't need to handle any navigation between the home and the sign up, if your user is signed in you will automatically be navigated to the home page.

another solution if that is not what you are looking for, after the google sign function finishes check if the firebase user is not null, if there is a user navigate to your homepage